# Union of increasing $\sigma$-algebras which is no $\sigma$-Algebra

Tags: measure-theory

> > Give an example for an increasing series of $\sigma$ algebras $$
> > \mathcal{A}_1\subset\mathcal{A}_2\subset\ldots
> > $$ 
> >     so that
> >     $$\bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty}\mathcal{A}_i
> > $$ is no $\sigma$-algebra.

Could you pls give me a hint how to find such an example?

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**: If I remember correctly, almost any example works, as long as $\mathcal A_i \subsetneq \mathcal A_{i+1}$, to give a concrete example think on **finite** $\sigma$-algebras $\mathcal A_i$ on $\mathbb N$, such that $\bigcup \mathcal A_i$ contains all singletons.

Comment: Would $F_n:=\left\{\left\{1\right\},\left\{2\right\},\ldots,\left\{n\right\}\right\}$, and then $\sigma(F_n)$ be an appropriate example?

Comment: Exactly this was the example i was thinking of.